# Need to get two values out into an array from string split

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var result = "y-9m-10y-9m-11y-0m-02y-0m-03";
```

I need to make 2 lists:
one for all the `y-` objects(9,9,0,0)
 and another for the `m-` objects(10,11,02,03). 
How can I do this?

I have this older code from before that doesn't care about the `y-` objects. Now I need to get both sets.

```
var result = "m-10m-11m-02m-03";
var months = result.Split(new[] { "m-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the number following each `y` or `m` flag? Like, you want to get `9, 9, 0, 0` from `y` and `10, 11, 02, 03` from `m`?

Comment: Looks like a job for regular expressions

Comment: I added the lists that I am looking for.

Comment: @user1566783 is length of "y-9m-10y-9m-11y-0m-02y-0m-03" fixed or is changed ?

Comment: The length will change. Also think I will try the regex route with some linq.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution using regular expressions and LINQ:

```cs
var months = Regex.Matches(result, @"m-(\d+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
var years = Regex.Matches(result, @"y-(\d+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Note that this doesn't do any error checking.

Edit: In the question you seem to use the extracted strings without converting them to `int`. In this case, omit the `int.Parse` and use `m.Groups[1].Value` directly.

Comment: While the idea here is spot on, this code doesn't actually compile. You missed a cast: `var months = Regex.Matches(result, @"m-(\d+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));`

Comment: @Sach That's interesting, this code does actually compile on my system. Which runtime are you using? I've tested on .NET Core 3.0.

Comment: Hmm that _is_ interesting. I tested this on a console program with `.NET Framework 4.7`.

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't compile with .NET Framework :D Nice find! I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: I mean it makes sense to me; in `.NET`, the return of `Regex.Matches()` is not an `IEnumerable` but a `MatchCollection`, so obviously it can't do a `Select` on it. Does `Regex.Matches()` return an `IEnumerable<Match>` on `Core`?

Comment: No, it also returns a MatchCollection. But it inherits from `IEnumerable<Match>`, while in .NET Framework it doesn't.